# How is let keyword block scoped in JavaScript if we can access it from outside the loop

Tags: javascript

for example: -

```js
let a = 10
if (true) {
    a = 20
}
console.log(a) // Gives 20
```

I am confused because I thought nothing inside { ... } this should be accessible outside. Please correct me if I am wrong, is it really like **if I declare some let inside { ... } I won't be able to access it outside like given below**

```js
let a = 10
if (true) {
    let a = 20
}
console.log(a) // Gives 10
```

On second thought I think I answered my own question. Please add your comments. thanks.

Comment: It's not a function so is public variable. obviously if condition is `false` for example `if(a==11)` the variable `a` will not accessible because it was not created

Comment: Everything *declared* is visible in the scope. `a` is declared outside. If you'd do `{ const test = 1; }` the you won't see `test` outside of the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing variable declaration with variable assignment.

In the first example `a` is declared with `let` at the top level. The block is *inside* the top level so `a` can be read from and written to inside the block.

In the section example `a` is also declared with `let` at the top level, however **another** `a` is declared inside the block. Changes to the `a` inside the block do not affect the `a` outside the block.